# How do I accept Game Center invites (or view notifications) on Apple TV?

Tags: notifications, appletv, game-center

If I'm playing a game on Apple TV and a friend invites me to join them (we're "nearby players"), I get a Game Center notification on my TV. But I can't figure out any way to accept the invite.

I've tried tapping and double tapping the TV button on my remote or navigating to the notification, but the notification disappears quickly and I can't seem to interact with it.

I've found [old posts](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7910270) suggesting there's a notification section in Settings, but I can't find it. The [Adjust Apple TV app settings help page](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/tv/atvbae11a68b/tvos) points me to Settings > Apps > TV but there's no Notification option there (even right after I send a Game Center invite).

How can I view notifications on Apple TV? Is it possible to accept Game Center invites?

Comment: Aren’t these two separate questions? You say you get notifications and then you ask how to view them. I would suggest you remove everything about notifications if someone doesn’t answer in a day or three with a good answer.

Comment: You mean "how to view notification" and "how to accept invite"? On iOS and macOS, you accept invites by opening the notification. I guess I'm assuming you do the same on tvOS, but maybe you do something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

You can press and hold the Menu (1st gen remote) or < (2nd gen remote) button when you see the invite notification to accept it.

Apparently the notification used to say "Hold Menu" but I guess they changed the label on the button and removed the text.